# Uniqueness of series for a given converging limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose there exists two infinite series with same convergence value. It is also provided that there exists an integer N, such that for all partial sums up to more than or equal to N terms, of both series are equal. Is it necessary for each term of the two series to be equal? Thank you.

Comment: No, this is not true at all, considering that we can just switch the order of addition for a finite number of terms in any sum and satisfy these conditions.

Comment: Ok how can we show that the set of numbers of form p/q where p and q are primes is dense in the set of real numbers.

Comment: @SohamGhosh do you have reason to believe this assertion is true? It is true those ratios can get arbitrarily close to 1 since we have the weak form of the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: @SohamGhosh what you would have to show is that any real number can be approximated by a sequence of ratios of prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $(1,2,3,0,0,0,0......)$ and $(3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0.....)$